# Hibernate query: join by map key

Tags: hibernate, dictionary, join, key

I have following classes:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> implements Serializable {
    protected long id;
    protected Map<Language,EntityMetaData> metaData;
...
public class Service extends Entity<Long> implements Serializable {
    protected String name;
```

XML mappings:

```
<class name="Service" table="SERVICES" schema="EDRIVE" dynamic-update="false" dynamic-insert="true" batch-size="30">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains definitions of relations between entities
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="long" column="id">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <map name="metaData" table="ServiceMetaData">
        <key column="serviceid"/>
        <map-key-many-to-many column="languageId" class="com.core.domain.Language"/>
        <one-to-many entity-name="serviceMetaData"/>
    </map>
</class>

<class name="EntityMetaData" entity-name="serviceMetaData" table="SERVICESMETADATA" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="id" access="field">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string" length="256" />
    <property name="description" column="description" type="string" length="512"/>
</class>
```

I want to load serviceMetadata only for particular language, ie, ru, en, uk etc:

```
Service serviceEntity = (Service) databaseUtilities
                .getSession()
                .createQuery("FROM Service s"
                        + " JOIN FETCH s.metaData m"
                        + " WHERE s.id = :id AND m.language = :language")
                .setParameter("id", serviceId)
                .setParameter("language", language)
                .uniqueResult();
```

where serviceId is long, language is an instance of Language class.

When I try the approach above, I get the following exception:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: language of:
> serviceMetaData [FROM com.core.domain.service.Service s JOIN FETCH
> s.metaData m WHERE s.id = :id AND m.language = :language]

In other case:

```
Service serviceEntity = (Service) databaseUtilities
                .getSession()
                .createQuery("FROM Service s"
                        + " WHERE s.id = :id AND s.metaData['language'] = :language")
                .setParameter("id", serviceId)
                .setParameter("language", language)
                .uniqueResult();
```

exception is

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for
> type integer: "language"   Position: 235

and CROSS JOIN!

Okay, removed any conditions, only service + all metadata belongs to it to see how it is constructed. Here is a serialized to JSON resultset:

```
"service": {
        "id": 5,
        "entityType": null,
        "entityKey": null,
        "metaData": {
            "com.core.domain.Language@57d41bfc": {
                "id": 2145,
                "entityType": null,
                "entityKey": null,
                "metaData": null,
                "miscMetaData": null,
                "name": "Заправка топливом",
                "description": null
            },
            "com.core.domain.Language@99ca0b20": {
                "id": 2144,
                "entityType": null,
                "entityKey": null,
                "metaData": null,
                "miscMetaData": null,
                "name": "Fueling",
                "description": null
            }
        },
        "miscMetaData": null,
        "name": "FUELING",
        "serviceType": {
            "id": 23,
            "entityType": null,
            "entityKey": null,
            "metaData": null,
            "miscMetaData": null,
            "value": "RECURRENT"
        }
    }
```

as you can see here, metaData consists of two objects (which is actually PersistentMap with key = Language).

So, the question is: how to retrieve particular map value by language with Hibernate?

Comment: Try `KEY(m)`. See [reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-collection-valued-associations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA demands that the state of managed entities and the database must be in sync at the end of a transaction, so fetching only a partial collection of an entity would essentially delete the non-fetched elements, which is why JPA does not allow this. You can however do it with Hibernate but I would not recommend it because it could lead to deletions.

So to get what you want, you need to write a HQL query and fetch data into DTOs. In the query, you select all fields you need and can define the join condition you as you like. Something like the following:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, m.id, m.name
FROM Service s
LEFT JOIN s.metadata m ON KEY(m) = 'en'
```

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Service.class)
public interface ServiceDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Mapping("metadata['en']")
    LanguageDto getLanguage();

    @EntityView(EntityMetaData.class)
    interface LanguageDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }

    // Other mappings
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ServiceDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ServiceDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Thank you!